# How Can i use Youwave (for android) as an emulator for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, youwave-for-android

I know that we can use Bluestacks as an emulator for Android Studio and other devices using

> **adb connect ip:port**

But is there any way to use Youwave as an emulator for developing purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use YouWave in the same way,

1. run command prompt in windows by typing "cmd" in the search field of the start menu
2. change the directory to "platform-tools" in your sdk folder. For example, suppose that your sdk is located in "c:\android\source\sdk\" use the command "cd c:\android\source\sdk\platform-tools" for changing the current directory.
3. Run the following command for connecting YouWave to AndroidStudio:
   "adb connect 127.0.0.1:5558"

Enjoy it!