# error connecting youwave to android studio

Tags: android, emulation

I want to connect Youwave to my android studio, so I created a bat file and wrote this 3 line of code in it:

```
F:
cd android-sdks\platform-tools

adb connect 127.0.0.1:5558

pause
```

and saved it.

When I run it, following error occurres:

> unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5558
>
> no connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it . (10061)

I searched to find a solution, there were some similiar errors for web services or python, but I coudn't find anything for youwave and android.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: did you try this answe on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/38183371/3678308 ?

Comment: @Javacoder  there is no diffrence actually